# SSL Error when installing pyinstaller even though I am able to install other libraries

Tags: python, ssl, pyinstaller

I am at a corporate environment and I am trying to make a single .exe file for my program. In this corporate environment, I have to use a proxy when installing libraries. For example:

```
pip --proxy https://web-proxy.xxx.xxx.net:8080 install pyinstaller
```

I am able to install all other libraries except for pyinstaller

I even tried installing the library on another jump station (in which you have to still use the corporate proxy) and I still couldn't install it. Here is the full trace back (keep in mind that my company still uses python 2.7):

```
 ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\python27\python.exe' 'c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\8\pip-build-env-m1s7oj\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-b
inary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel:
  DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:661)'),)': /simple/setuptools/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:661)'),)': /simple/setuptools/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:661)'),)': /simple/setuptools/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:661)'),)': /simple/setuptools/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:661)'),)': /simple/setuptools/
    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/setuptools/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCE
SS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:661)'),)) - skipping
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1
 alert access denied (_ssl.c:661)'),)) - skipping
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\python27\python.exe' 'c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\8\pip-build-env-m1s7oj\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https:
//pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel" failed with error code 1 in None
```

I don't get that traceback when install any other library, only this one. I guess I have to go home and install it there ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what Python version you are installing to. 
In my setup I also have a python2.7 and it was being called while I am installing the pyinstaller library. I am using Python3.4 in my virtual environment(.venv)

You have to go to the specific environment where you want to install the pyinstaller.
e.g

```
(.ven) C:\Python\Development>C:\Python\Development\.venv\Scripts\python -m pip install pyinstaller
```

This will call the python from the specified environment and execute the pip module for installing the library.

sample output:

```
Collecting pyinstaller
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/c9/0b44b2ea87ba36395483
a672fddd07e6a9cb2b8d3c4a28d7ae76c7e7e1e5/PyInstaller-3.5.tar.gz (3.5MB)
    100% |################################| 3.5MB 148kB/s
```